# Xcode - logictest vs applicationtest

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing

I am building my first iPhone app, and I want to get started with unit testing.
Been reading up on it and there are two sides to it. logictests and applicationtest.
logictest seems to me like regular unit testing.
applicationtesting sounds to me like gui-interaction testing.
Is that correct? Should i do both or is logictest sufficient?
I am considering just testing CRUD operations of objects in my logictest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find Apple's distinction artificial and limiting. By using a different test framework ([GTM](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/) in my case, or you might try [GHUnit](http://gabriel.github.com/gh-unit/)) you can just write tests without asking yourself, "Where does this test belong?" I write tests against view controllers that are not interaction tests.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Ironically, I'm now investigating the built-in test framework in Xcode 4. Even if it's still awkward, the benefits of being fully integrated may offset things. We'll see…

Comment: Assessment: Xcode 4 fixes everything that was wrong with Xcode 3's integrated testing for iOS. Able to debug in one step. Test bundle is injected into your app (the way it's been done on Mac OS X), so no need to compile all your sources into a separate testing app. No need for separate logictests and applicationtest. I'm switching back.

Comment: so no benefit of going with GHUnit now over the inbuild SenTestingKit that comes with XCode 4?

Comment: @Greg - I'm not saying there are no benefits (especially since I haven't tried GHUnit). But it is definitely worth investigating the native Xcode 4 setup for yourself.